# Spring Integration : Logging using logging-channel-adapter + log4j

Tags: log4j, spring-integration

I am trying to log some details in the DB using log4j. I have configured the logging-channel-adapter as the wire-tap.

The required logger is the dbappender but the same is not working.

**spring-integration.xml**

```
<int:wire-tap channel="logChannel"/>
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logChannel" level="INFO" logger-name="AUDIT_the.details" />
```

**log4j.xml**

```
<logger name="AUDIT_the.details">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="asyncAppender" />
    </logger>

    <appender name="asyncAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
        <param name="blocking" value="false" />
        <appender-ref ref="dbAppender" />
    </appender>

    <appender name="dbAppender" class="LoggerTemplate">
        <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <param name="sql"
            value="SQL_QUERY" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="info" />
    </appender>
```

Comment: Well, if you say, that it doesn't work, you should, at least, point out where it is. Haven't you tried simple logging to the console? Or how does it work with `direct` appender, bypassing `AsyncAppender` ? Not enough info to figure out an issue... And... What is `LoggerTemplate` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have configured a wiretap channel but you also need to put that in some interceptor tag for the channel you want to intercept.Not sure if you have done that as its missing in your post. Below is one example.

```
<integration:channel id="mydbchannel-to-intercept">
    <integration:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logChannel"/>
    </integration:interceptors>
</integration:channel>
```